# Obtain SQL Login account password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there anyway I can obtain a SQL Login account password, I did not create the logins so I would like to see what the password is for a certain SQL login.

Thanks!

Comment: No this cannot be done. You will need to reset the password via sysadmin login.

Comment: More details are needed. Why do you need this login information, and have you checked records locally? Because the general answer is "no", and the specific answer is "Not unless you change the password or it is somewhere in your records."

Comment: still using sql 2005 ??

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/293501ea-30e0-4d60-99ac-b503ff42f2fa/how-to-find-user-login-password-in-sql-server?forum=sqlgetstarted

Answer (score 3):

If it's a sql login and you have access to the application servers, you could look for it in connection strings on those. Otherwise, there is no way to find the password.  Your only option is to reset the password.